# Fourier transform integration in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have to calculate the Fourier transform of an acceleration data that I've already coded. I have to do it the old fashion way (I mean, without the numpy np.fft.fft command, even though I don't master that neither) So, this is what I have for the integration:

```
ri = 1j                     # first time defining a complex number in python
Fmax = 50                   # Hz, the maximum frequency to consider
df = 0.01                   # frequency diferential
nf = int(Fmax / df)         # number of sample points for frequency
# and I already have UD_Acc defined as a 1D numpy array, then the "for loop":

Int_UD = []     
for i in range(UD_Acc.size):
    w = []
    for j in range(nf):
        w.append(2 * np.pi * df * (j - 1))
    Int_UD.append(Int_UD[i - 1] + UD_Acc[i] * np.exp(ri * w * (i - 1) * dt1))
```

First of all, in the **for loop** the *w* variable has a warning as:

> Expected type 'complex', got 'List[Union[Union[float, int], Any]]' instead

And then, even if I run it, it says that the list index is out of range.
I know it may seem a little rudiment to integrate like this, or to find a Fourier transform without using scipy or np.fft, but is for class, and I'm trying to understand the basics, so thanks in advance.

Comment: `range` starts from `0` so in your first iteration you get the IndexError as you do  `Int_UD[i - 1]` so you want to put something at `Int_UD[-1]` which does not exist. Should it just be `Int_UD[i]`?

Comment: Nope, that didn't worked. I think that I got a problem with the 2 ranges, the one for (i) and the other for (j)

Comment: The second `IndexError` comes from the `UD_Acc[i]` that you defined above your loop.  You request the value at `i` in `UD_Acc[i] ` but that does not work as it's an empty list, there is no value there